# 2D Simplex Smooth Cave Generation

Tags: xna, c#, 2d, simplex-noise

So I'm creating a system of caves below my random terrain generation, and I'm using 2D Simplex Noise to do so and I have a pretty good grasp on generating the random caves.  However, the cutoff from the terrain to where the cave layer starts is a bit abrupt, and I was wondering how I could prevent this.

Random Level Generation:

```
public static Level GetRandomLevel(int rows, int cols, float scale = 1f)
{
    Tile[][] tiles = new Tile[rows][];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        tiles[i] = new Tile[cols];
        for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
        {
            tiles[i][x] = new Tile(0, new Vector2(x, i), scale);
        }
    }
    int left = Main.rand.Next(rows / 4, rows / 2);

    double seed = Main.rand.NextDouble() * 255;
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        float noise = Noise.Generate((float)seed);
        noise *= 7;
        int height = left + (int)noise;
        height = (int)MathHelper.Clamp(height, 0, rows - 1);
        tiles[height][i] = new Tile(2, new Vector2(i, height), scale);
        FillLower(tiles, height, i, scale);
        seed += .05f;
    }

    int[] heightmap = new int[cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            if (tiles[j][i].TileID == 2)
            {
                heightmap[i] = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Smoothing out terrain
    for (int i = 0; i < cols - 1; i++)
    {
        if (heightmap[i] > heightmap[i + 1])
        {
            tiles[heightmap[i] - 1][i] = new Tile(6, new Vector2(i, heightmap[i] - 1), scale);
            tiles[heightmap[i]][i] = new Tile(3, new Vector2(i, heightmap[i]), scale);
        }
    }
    for (int i = cols - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (heightmap[i] > heightmap[i - 1])
        {
            tiles[heightmap[i] - 1][i] = new Tile(5, new Vector2(i, heightmap[i] - 1), scale);
            tiles[heightmap[i]][i] = new Tile(4, new Vector2(i, heightmap[i]), scale);
        }
    }

    //Caves
    for (int y = 0; y < rows && left + 10 + y < rows; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
        {
            double noise = Noise.Generate(x / (70 * scale), (y + 1) / (70 * scale));
            //Not air
            if (tiles[left + 10 + y][x].TileID != 0 && noise > 0)
            {
                tiles[left + 10 + y][x] = new Tile(0, new Vector2(x, left + 10 + y), scale);
            }

        }
    }

    return new Level(tiles);
}
```

Here is a picture demonstrating what I mean about the 'cave layer cutoff' being to abrupt.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and looped along the starting point of the caves from left to right and used a recursive method to fill in all the caves that started at the top of the cave layer, thereby removing any cutoffs.

```
//Looping along cave layer
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
{
    if (tiles[left + 10][i].TileID == 0)
    {
        FillCaves(tiles, left + 10, i, scale);
    }
}

private static void FillCaves(Tile[][] tiles, int i, int j, float scale)
{
    tiles[i][j] = new Tile(1, new Vector2(j, i), scale);
    if (i - 1 >= 0 && tiles[i - 1][j].TileID == 0)
    {
        FillCaves(tiles, i - 1, j, scale);
    }
    if (i + 1 < tiles.Length && tiles[i + 1][j].TileID == 0)
    {
        FillCaves(tiles, i + 1, j, scale);
    }
    if (j - 1 >= 0 && tiles[i][j - 1].TileID == 0)
    {
        FillCaves(tiles, i, j - 1, scale);
    }
    if (j + 1 < tiles[i].Length && tiles[i][j + 1].TileID == 0)
    {
        FillCaves(tiles, i, j + 1, scale);
    }
}
```

[image: As you can see, there is no longer an odd cutoff.]

Answer (score 0):

Foreach column , jump the air tiles over ground , then start to apply 2d noise.
In pseudo code:

```
  //Caves
Foreach cols {
 Bool FoundFirstGround=false;
 Foreach rows //from top
 {
  if (FoundFirstGround){
    //APPLY YOUR 2d simplex noise logic
    ...
  }
  else
    //jump air tiles over surface
    if (! is air){
       FoundFirstGround=true;   
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I think this would only work if the top of the noise doesn't have any cutoffs.